# Percentage difference between any two columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to have a function defined for percentage diff calculation between any two pandas columns.
Lets say that my dataframe is defined by:

```
R1  R2    R3    R4   R5    R6
 A   B     1     2    3     4
```

I would like my calculation defined as

```
df['R7'] = df[['R3','R4']].apply( method call to calculate perc diff)
```

and

```
df['R8'] = df[['R5','R6']].apply(same method call to calculate perc diff)
```

How can i do that?

I have tried below

```
df['perc_cnco_error'] = df[['CumNetChargeOffs_x','CumNetChargeOffs_y']].apply(lambda x,y: percCalc(x,y))

def percCalc(x,y):
    if x<1e-9:
        return 0
    else:
        return (y - x)*100/x
```

and it gives me the error message

> TypeError: ('() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)',
> u'occurred at index CumNetChargeOffs_x')

Comment: `apply` does row-wise operation unless you specify the `axis` keyword argument as 1. So try doing `lambda x: percCalc(x['R3'], x['R4'])` and see if it works!

Comment: Works with a small change lambda x: percCalc(x['R3'], x['R4']), axis=1 Thank you!

Comment: Oh oops... i had the axes the other way around. My bad!

Answer (score 23):

At its simplest terms:

```
def percentage_change(col1,col2):
    return ((col2 - col1) / col1) * 100
```

You can apply it to any 2 columns of your dataframe:

```
df['a'] = percentage_change(df['R3'], df['R4'])    
df['b'] =  percentage_change(df['R6'], df['R5'])

>>> print(df)
 
  R1 R2  R3  R4  R5  R6      a     b
0  A  B   1   2   3   4  100.0 -25.0
```

Equivalently using `pandas` arithmetic operation functions

```
def percentage_change(col1,col2):
    return col2.sub(col1).div(col1).mul(100)
```

- [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html)
- [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html)
- [`Series.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html)

---

You can also utilise `pandas` built-in [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html)  which computes the percentage change across all the columns passed, and select the column you want to return:

```
df['R7'] = df[['R3', 'R4']].pct_change(axis=1)['R4']
df['R8'] = df[['R6', 'R5']].pct_change(axis=1)['R5']

>>> print(df)

  R1 R2  R3  R4  R5  R6      a     b   R7    R8
0  A  B   1   2   3   4  100.0 -25.0  1.0 -0.25
```

---

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'R1':'A','R2':'B',
                   'R3':1,'R4':2,'R5':3,'R6':4},
                  index=[0])
```

Answer (score 4):

To calculate percent diff between `R3` and `R4` you can use:

```
df['R7'] = (df.R3 - df.R4) / df.R3 * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the deviation in percentage:

```
df.apply(lambda row: (row.iloc[0]-row.iloc[1])/row.iloc[0]*100, axis=1)
```

If you have more than two columns try,

```
df[['R3', 'R5']].apply(lambda row: (row.iloc[0]-row.iloc[1])/row.iloc[0]*100, axis=1)
```