# Percentage difference every 2 columns of pandas dataframe and generate a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large pandas dataframe similar to the one below:

```
Number    A_white   A_black   B_white   B_black    ...   AUV_white   AUV_black
140       0.010    0.567     0.001     0.0075            1.0         1.5
150       100      200       500       1000        ...   500         1000
```

I am trying to generate a new dataframe with the following data:

```
Number    A          B         ...       AUV
140       193.068    152.941             40     
150       66.667     66.667              66.667
```

In the new dataframe:

```
new_df['A'] = (old_df.A_white - df.A_black).abs() / ((old_df.A_white + df.A_black)/2) * 100
```

There is a similar solution: [Percentage difference between any two columns of pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100058/percentage-difference-between-any-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe)

But I have a large dataframe and can't really do it with column names. Is there a way I can use, `loc` or `iloc` to attain the results?

For col names of the new dataframe I have:

```
col_names = old_df.columns
col_names = col_names.tolist()
col_names = [x.replace("_white", "") for x in col_names]
del col_names[1::2]
```

Comment: Do you want to group all columns that have them same string before the underscore?  So, sum A_black A_white together then B_white with B_black and so on?

Comment: I want to find the percentage difference between them, but the logic of selection of cols you mentioned is correct.

Comment: Can you break down the calculation? The logic is unclear

Comment: I edited to add that, hopefully that clarified it

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it was not obvious to guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your index to MultiIndex and use [advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-xs) with [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html#pandas.DataFrame.xs):

```
# set non white/black columns aside
df = df.set_index('Number')
# split to MultiIndex
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns.str.split('_').to_list())

# select cross-sections
w = df.xs('white', level=1, axis=1)
b = df.xs('black', level=1, axis=1)

# perform the computation
df2 = (abs(w-b)/(w+b)*200).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Number           A           B        AUV
0     140  193.067591  152.941176  40.000000
1     150   66.666667   66.666667  66.666667
```